# Can we print inside a function with a return in Python?

Tags: python, function, return

I wonder if I can print a message inside a Python function that already returns a value. Would the print output appear when I call it from the main program, or will I just get the value returned?

For example:

```
def test(x,y)
    if x>y :
        print('x is bigger then y')
        return x
    else:
        print('y is bigger then x')
        return y
```

Comment: Your comment don't help anyone. @smarx I'm starting with this language and get in trouble with print. His question help me to understand better my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how you decide to call your function.
Because your function has a `return` value, you would normally print out the results by doing `print(test(x, y))` Doing this, however, would also print the `print` statement as well. 
If you were to just call the function `test(x, y)`, you would get the print message, but it would **not** print the result for `return x`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, print() will print to stdout. Yes, it will still happen if you call the function in another function.

Answer (score 0):

yes it would. If the print statement is placed before a return statement it'll print to stdout
Try it out